# Asp.Net TreeView - making the text unclickable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, treeview, postback

I happen to have stumbled upon an issue (neither MSDN nor Google searching seem to assist me in this scenario).

I have an ASP:TreeView module inside a WebForms page that lists some dynamically generated data. As parent-child check box checking affects the other elements as well, I am doing a postback every time a value is changed.

That is working completely fine. The issue is, though, when the user clicks on the string representation of the data instead of the checkbox that's next to it, the whole thing seems to fall apart and then postbacks are no longer happening, even when clicking on a checkbox.

Is there a way to make the text values unclickable?

It does sound like a fairly simple thing, but I've wasted an incredible amount of time trying to solve it, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

After even more continuous trial and testing, it turns out that the solution is fairly simple. When you're populating the treeview (creating individual nodes), you can set:

```
node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
```

which renders the textual representation unclickable. Hope this helps someone.